# Disable submit button while processing form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have the following code that works well :

```
$(function() {
      $("input,textarea").jqBootstrapValidation({
            preventSubmit: true,
            submitError: function($form, event, errors) {
              // additional error messages or events
            },
            submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
                event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
                // get values from FORM
                var name = $("input#name").val();
                var email = $("input#email").val();
                var phone = $("input#phone").val();
                var message = $("textarea#message").val();
                var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
                // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
                if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                  firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
                }
                $.ajax({
                      url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                      type: "POST",
                      data: {
                        name: name,
                        phone: phone,
                        email: email,
                        message: message
                      },
                      cache: false,
                      success: function() {
                        // Success message
                        $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;").append("</button>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').append("<strong>Su mensaje fue enviado. </strong>");
                        $('#success > .alert-success').append('</div>');
                        //clear all fields
                        $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                        ga('send', 'event', {
                          eventCategory: 'Contactos',
                          eventAction: 'Envio contacto',
                          eventLabel: 'Español'
                        });
                      },
```

I want that while the form Sending button used to run out , so you can not send him back while processing
as I leave the submit button disabled while sending ?
the button code is :

```
<button class="btn btn-xl2" type="submit">Enviar </button>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your HTML button code is missing, also your description is not very clear. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 2):

Disable it in:

```
submitSuccess: function($form, event) {
    $('#contactForm').find('.btn.btn-xl2').prop('disabled', true);
    /*...*/
}
```

And add `complete` callback to ajax method:

```
complete: function(){
    $('#contactForm').find('.btn.btn-xl2').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

Comment: Looks like it is wiser way than mine :)

Answer (score 1):

Add this before $.ajax({

```js
$('.btn-xl2').attr('disabled','disabled')
```

Add this in success function

```js
$('.btn-xl2').removeAttr('disabled')
```

Comment: `prop()` method is prefered as for jq 1.6 for boolean attribute

Answer (score 0):

For me it would be just enought to do some HTML/CSS manipulation.

For example you can change looks of that button and remove `type="submit"` parameter for a time when request is processing (so in this case you should remove it when script starts and get it back when it finishes).

Of course it is not the best way, but I believe the easiest.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. Where's your "solution"?